# Setting the validity of a Angular 2 control from within a custom component

Tags: forms, angular

I have a custom Ng2 component a I am using the Model-Driven approach.

```
<form [ngFormModel]="myForm" class="layout vertical relative">
    <my-custom-comp ngControl="currentValue"></my-custom-comp>
</form>
```

So inside my custom component I have all the logic I need but I can't find a way to get a reference to the ngControl to set it to valid or invalid from inside my custom component.

Comment: you can give the whole control to component in the way [foo] or [(foo)]. the way just add control in same .ts file and pass whole control to the component [foo]="fbgroup.find('currentValue')"

Comment: I found a way to get "a" or "the" NgControl (atm I am not sure which one I am getting) via  
```this._control = this._injector.get(NgControl, null);``` but I don't know how to set it to invalid to test it...

Comment: I guess you can just inject `NgControl` `constructor(private ngControl:NgControl)` into your component without injecting the injector and getting it from there. In `NgControl` you can add additional validators or use `setErrors()` (not tested)

Comment: I tried to inject the NgControl but i am getting ```Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! NgControlName``` I did try to and ```@SkipSelf() @Host() @Optional()``` but the error remains

Comment: The cyclic dependency error was coming from the Vaadin VAADIN_DATE_PICKER_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-date-picker/blob/master/directives/vaadin-date-picker.ts see below for answer.

Comment: Hi, any advance on this case?

Answer (score 7):

You can check this link for a working example: https://github.com/byavv/angular2-playground/tree/master/client/app/modules/forms_explore

Some key aspects:
You need to implement ControValueAccessor.

```
export class Datepicker implements ControlValueAccessor {
```

Inject in your component the ngControl and register it:

```
constructor(private ngControl:NgControl)
ngControl.valueAccessor = this;
```

From within your component you should have a form that validates the field so you can subscribe to emit the correct value or set the error of the parent ngControl form.

```
 this.dateForm = builder.group({
          dateControl: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, CustomValidators.frenchDate])],
        });

    this.dateForm.valueChanges
      .subscribe((val) => {
        if (this.dateForm.valid) {
          this.onChange.emit(this.dateToTimestamp(val.dateControl));
        } else {
          this.ngControl.control.setErrors({ "wrongDate": true });
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.myForm.controls['currentValue']....
```

but there is currently no way to explicitely set it to `valid` or `invalid`.

You can define a validator and change the criteria so it marks the control invalid.

See for example https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4933

Comment: I don't have access to ```this.myForm``` from within the component. The custom validator is an idea but it feel like a roundabout way of doing it... is there an event that I can emit to trigge the invalid state ?

Comment: Not as far as I know. Can you provide more code. To me its not clear what you're actually doing or trying to accomplish. You might want to pass the form or control into your custom component.

Comment: I am writing a custom component, (a datepicker) the validity check is implemented within the component. From the exterior I would like to use it as a normal form input. So I would add the ngControl and register it to a ngFormModel. Is that clearer ?

Comment: I guess you should just implement `ControlValueAccessor` (there exist several answers already)

Comment: basically its the same as https://vaadin.com/elements/-/element/vaadin-date-picker A standard component that is connected to a ngFormModel

Comment: I have implemented ```ControlValueAccessor``` but I don't see where or how to set the validity

Comment: @Brett I'm having exactly the same issue

Answer (score 0):

> How to set **VALID** or **INVALID** on any formGroup

```
// Where this.form === FormGroup;
// FormGroup can be deeply nested, just call at the level you want to update.
// That level should have direct access to base FormControls

// Can be done in a validator function;
this.form.get('name').setErrors({required: true});
// => this.form.get('name').invalid === true;

// Perhaps on Submit, click, event NOT in validator function
Object.entries(this.form.controls).forEach(([key, ctrl]) => {
  ctrl.updateValueAndValidity();
});
// => this.form.get('name').invalid === false;
// => this.form.get('name').valid === true;
// => this.form.get('name').errors === null;
```

Comment: might not be the required solution for this question but it worked for what I needed! thanks